# ssh -X/-Y slow to terminate, hangs on single command. Fix: don't do -X/-Y, but why?

Tags: ssh, openssh, x11-forwarding

Note: I'm unable to reproduce this issue on a Linux workstation, only see it when initiating ssh from a MacOS Catalina machine (SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4).

I had `ForwardX11 yes` & `ForwardX11Trusted yes` in my .ssh/config file. Since long ago, I noticed that ssh sessions were terribly slow to terminate, but had "no time to investigate". Now, when logging into an RHEL8 machine, single command sessions would hang completely. -vvv reported unclosed "things", and after some experimentation I found that X11 forwarding was the culprit. Funnily enough, forwarding of other ports seems not to be a problem.

The question is... why? Something to do with X11 authentication??

(I asked this question a bit earlier today without logging in, then something happened when trying to sign up here - can't find that now so since I have the explanation/fix I'm posting again)

Comment: Stackoverflow is for help with software development. You should consider asking questions like this on [unix.se], [su], or maybe [apple.se].

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I'm apparently a bit confused about the relationship between stack overflow versus stack exchange/serverfault. That's probably what caused the login issues yesterday. Both "sites" show the same correspondence, yet they are not the same?